# HTML-Email isn't rendering in font "tahoma" on mobile

Tags: html, css, email, fonts

I want to send an HTML-Mail which uses the font "tahoma". It works on desktops but it doesn't use font "tahoma" on mobile clients.

How could I solve this?

Here is the mail I send:

```html
<h3 style="color:#626262; font-size:14px; line-height:18px; margin:0 0 5px 15px; font-family: Tahoma,Verdana,Segoe,sans-serif; font-weight:700">
 
 XYZ 
        
 <span class="sapretor">&nbsp;&nbsp; | &nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
        
 <span class="full" style="color: #626262;font-family: Tahoma,Verdana,Segoe,sans-serif; font-weight: 400;">
  Art Director
 </span>
        
</h3>
```

Comment: Where is the "code"?

Comment: so you have posted all this code just because you a problem in rendering font !!

btw your code works fine.

Comment: Hi Mohammad, issue occur in mobile device when i paste this code to signature.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that **Tahoma isn't installed on mobiles**. There are only a few font which work on all devices.

Some websites will tell you that Tahoma is cross browser (or web-save) but that is not true, since it doesn't work on mobiles. This is also true for eMail as because both websites and eMails use the same font pool on the device/computer.

There is currently not a good way to solve this. You can use it as first priority and just have a fallback option.

Comment: hey Omix, its not a webpage then how can i add external link to signature code. please suggest... and tahoma is a system font..

Comment: @NarendraDhakad I changed my answer, does it help you? if so please accept it or specify your question.